# How to memorise new words?

Tags: meaning, nouns, vocabulary

I usually spend a lot of time learning new words. It is very difficult to keep them in my brain. I prefer watching cartoons and CNN news (sometimes with subtitles).

But, anyway, my listening and speaking skills are horrible. How do people memorize words? I'm nervous, because I'm going to visit Europe, and I'm worried teachers won't understand me. :(

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm sorry, I think this is off-topic for us here, partly because this is a language learning question, rather than a question about English itself, and this site here is the one for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. And partly because this is really more about memorisation and language learning generally, than it is about learning English specifically

Comment: I can't remember names unless I write them down.  You have to experiment with what works for you.  Maybe writing a word down, maybe saying it aloud, maybe a combination....Also, focus on the words you will need.  You can't possibly memorize everything you hear, so be selective.

Comment: Going to Eutope from where? And speaking what language while you're there? Elementary tips: flash cards, find sentences in context for the vocab item that are meaningful. Eg not 'the dress was scarlet' but 'the dress was as scarlet as a blushing boiled lobster'

Comment: I use my mobile phone to keep my new words as a document which reminds me a dictionary with translation but I suppose, it doesn't help me...

Comment: Mitch, I'm going to visit Europe as an exchange student and my lessons are going to be in English...so...my English isn't perfect. How do you think, I'm beginner or not? :) How many mistakes were made?

Comment: From your writing, I'd say advanced beginner.  It's harder to speak than to write, I know!  And it is harder to understand  speech than a book.  One edit, because you asked for critique:  "What do you think: am I a beginner or not?"

Comment: ab2, I'm surprised. Can we use two questions in the one sentence? Look carefully... "what do you think?" Ok, it is normal but the second one must inherit positive structure, doesn't it? I assume, you made mistake "What do you think: am I a beginner or not"

Comment: You may know more than I do!  This is the problem with being merely a native speaker with a good ear whose last grammar lesson was in the 20th century.  Thinking about it:  "What do you think -- am I a beginner or not?" or "What do you think?  Am I a beginner or not?"  are better.  Saying it out loud, I'd go for the dash, because I don't hear myself giving two upward (questioning) inflections.  But if I were writing a formal paper, I'd be very sparing with dashes.

Comment: To learn a word you have to use it.

Comment: I'd recommend a site called https://quizlet.com. You can create your own digital flash cards and study them in a variety of ways. Most features are entirely free to use. There are some enhanced audio features that could help with your listening/speaking skills for only $14.99 a year, so it's a pretty affordable option. I used the site throughout high school and college when learning Spanish.

Comment: Avoid flash cards, word lists, and literary canons.  Read easy books, lots of them, nothing difficult, if need be start with children's books or comic strips, pulp fiction, lurid nonfiction, etc. and limit things not to your interest, or you'll forget what you like, and via peer pressure you'll zombie through books that dislike you.  *Interest is everything*.  Little books lead to bigger books, and vocabulary will inevitably accumulate.  When someone speaks a word or phrase you don't know, ask them what it means, do not pretend.  Interests pursued make for experience, and eventually taste.

Answer (score 1):

1: Watch movies

2: Have a vocabulary book where you have keep updating it by adding new vocabulary. and every couple of days go through this book.

3: Try to use the new words

4: Add visuals to your learning